# Encoding issue in JSF and Java

Tags: java, encoding, jsf-1.2

In JSF 1.2 app, when users copy/paste something from a Word doc (Windows-1252 encoded), into an input area in our JSF app (UTF-8 encoded by default) while browser encoding is whatever encoding the end-user is using (defaults to what OS they are using(often windows-1252 or ISO), all of the single and double quote characters are stripped from the value stored in the backing bean immediately.

What I have tried to combat this effect:

In the server.xml, in the `<connector>` tag I placed `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`.
In the `<meta>` tag I state `charset="UTF-8"`.
In the setter for the backing bean I write convert the string to UTF-8 encoded `byte[]`, then convert back to `String`.  The `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml` is supposed to take care of converting HTML entity numbers into proper format, and the replaces handle other representations of ISO and UTF encoding.

```
public void setInputNoteText(String inputNoteText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] utf8Bytes = inputNoteText.getBytes("UTF8");      
    String backToStr = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF8");           
    String inputNoteUtf8 = backToStr.replace("?" , "&#8226").replace("ï§", "&#8226").replace("Ã¯ÂÂ§" , "&#8226").replace("ÂX" , "&#8226").replace("&#61607" , "&#8226").replace("Ã¢ÂÂ" , "\'").replace("Â¡Â¥" , "\'").replace("Â¡Â¦" , "\'").replace("Â¡Â§" , "\"").replace("Â¡Â¨" , "\"").replace("Â", "\'").replace("â" , "\'");
    inputNoteUtf8 = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(backToStr);
    this.inputNoteText = inputNoteUtf8;
}
```

Can I force the user's browser into UTF-8 some way other than what I've tried so far? Or can anyone spot what I need to adjust?  I'm running out of ideas.